# tab bar not in main xib iphone

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

how can I implement a tab bar controller in a window that is not the mainWindow.xib ??
are there any examples,
or just what shall I connect to accomplish this?
tnx!

Comment: oh I forgot to say this> my second view, comes from a navigation controller! so the tab will be inside a nav controller, thank you!

Comment: so to set the UITabBarController normally, I will need to reference it in the *AppDelegate.h, but, that will be connected to the main view??. so where do i set the TabBar*Appdelegate?? do I change the *.h of my view called from the navigation??, hope this makes sense!, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITabBarController is not intended to be pushed on as/or added to another view except of the root view(window) of your application. So what you are saying is you want a UITabBarController to appear inside a UINavigationController. However this is not "allowed". The UITabBarController is intended as a solid point of navigation, think of the Windows "Start-bar", it always remains at that fixed position.

To achieve this in code you could add the the UITabBarController to your window in the appdelegate. Then add UINavigationController to the different tabs in your application.

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I see, thank you, so can I just fake it? like putting buttons on the bottom that go to different views inside?, ha I guess, cheers

Comment: No problem, I thought I could do not so long ago. Euhm yes you can "fake" it, though you will not get exactly the same visual "expression" by using the UIToolBar. On the UIToolBar you can add a UISegmentedswitch or use the UIBarButtonItem and add to the toolbar. When using this approach you will loose the overlay effect that you get for free when using the UITabBar. You are also required to program the behaviour of loading of and on views, for example you could add a UINavigationBarController(add the toolbar to the bottom of screen on this view) then push/pop viewcontrollers without animation.